# Extraction of the data from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `status_info_private` WHERE `id`=$id ORDER BY `Status_Date` DESC LIMIT 100";
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
        echo '<a href="view_profile.php?id=' . $id . '"><font color="#009900" > ' . $rows['Name'] . ' ' . ' Says :' . '</font></a><br/>';
        echo '<p align="justify> ' . $rows['Private_status'] . '<br/>';
        echo '<p align="right">' . $rows['Status_Date'] . '<br/>';
        $like   = $rows['Like'];
        $unlike = $rows['Unlike'];
    }
}
```

I think everything is correct in the piece of code. But still I am unable to get the output under the column titled as "Private_status". The above code is producing everything correctly except the message under cols "Private_status". I have already checked the spelling of the col name & there is no error in that part. 
So, Please tell me what exactly is missing ?

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated. As well as `align=` attribute on the `<p>` element. Please learn about CSS.

Comment: can you place print_r($rows) in while loop and get us the result?

Comment: Also, what is the output you're getting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: @ Madara Uchiha I am not an expert in CSS but i am sure we can use align attribute in <p> element. By the way problem is not styling...

Comment: we understand that the problem is not styling but there is no harm in getting good things..

Comment: @ Rishi Kalia I completely agree with your point and i love to get the good things. But will we please concentrate on solving the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `status_info_private` WHERE `id`=$id ORDER BY `Status_Date` DESC LIMIT 100";
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
        echo '<a href="view_profile.php?id=' . $id . '" color="#009900" > ' . $rows['Name'] . ' ' . ' Says :' . '</a><br/>';
        echo '<p align="justify"> ' . $rows['Private_status'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p align="right">' . $rows['Status_Date'] . '</p>';
        $like   = $rows['Like'];
        $unlike = $rows['Unlike'];
    }
}
```

Comment: :- Still not working. As i have already mentioned styling is not a problem in extraction of data from the database. By the way thanx for your help...

Answer (score 1):

first close your `<p>` tags and then do a `print_r` to check what is in `$rows`
..
Also, start using *PDO* or *mysqli*

Comment: closing of the <p> tags is not a problem. Since <p> is a singular tag.